# Is it good practice to use static variables in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static-variables

I have a question concerning best practices in rails.
In my rails project I have the following code:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def some_method
    @product = MyFabricatorClass.new.create_product
  end

  ...
end
```

MyFabricatorClass is not dependent of some state and its behaviour is constant. I am also doing a lot of C++ stuff and to me it feels kind of unefficient to always instantiate a new MyFabricatorClass object. In a C++ project I would propably use something like:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  @@my_fabricator = nil

  def some_method
    @@my_fabricator ||= MyFabricatorClass.new
    @product = @@my_fabricator.create_product
  end

  ...
end
```

Is this style also legit in Rails? What would be the typical rails way to do it?

Thanks for any advice...!

Comment: Why not make `create_product` a class method on `MyFabricatorClass`?

Comment: @jvillian: Thanks for your comment. Sorry, I've chosen bad naming. MyFabricatorClass isn't realls my class but 3rd party. So, changing MyFabricatorClass is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a better practice to not use class variables (those that start with `@@`) in ruby; [see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762366/are-ruby-class-variables-bad)

This might look like a weird code, but this is the more conventional way:

You set a "class" instance variable, instead of setting a "class variable".

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  @my_fabricator = nil

  class << self
    def some_method
      @my_fabricator ||= MyFabricatorClass.new
      @product = @my_fabricator.create_product
    end
  end
end
```

About `class << self`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645306/what-does-class-self-mean-in-rails)

The above code is just the same as:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  @my_fabricator = nil

  def self.some_method
    @my_fabricator ||= MyFabricatorClass.new
    @product = @my_fabricator.create_product
  end
end
```

Now you can just do:

```
MyController.some_method
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and the additional resources. Accepted and upvoted.

Comment: are there any differences if I declare `@my_fabricator` inside `class << self` block ? thanks

Comment: @hqt Yes, if you declare `@my_fabricator` outside `class << self`, those become instance variables for the object `MyController` (which is an instance of `Class`). If you declare them inside however, those become instance variables for the object `<Class:MyController>` (which is the singleton class object of `MyController`). Singleton class is like "where the methods are defined for that specific object". i.e.: `puts MyController.new.singleton_class` will show `#<Class:#<MyController:0x00007fa5b21ee588>>` while `puts MyController.singleton_class` will show `#<Class:MyController>`

Comment: @hqt see [this SO for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429693/singleton-method-vs-class-method)