# What is the 'self' keyword doing exactly in this Class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods, self

```
  class Restaurant

  attr_accessor :average_rating, :city

  def initialize(city, name)
    @city = city
    @name = name
    @number_of_ratings = 0
    @sum_of_ratings = 0
  end

  def rate(new_rate)
    @number_of_ratings += 1
    @sum_of_ratings += new_rate
    @average_rating = @sum_of_ratings.to_f / @number_of_ratings
  end

  def self.filter_by_city(restaurants, city)
    restaurants.select { |restaurant| restaurant.city == city }
  end
end
```

The above code is part of a challenge and I kept failing the tests for the #filter_by_city method. I checked the solution and the only difference was the `self.` prior to the method name. I've tried to understand what `self` does exactly but it's difficult to understand without context. In this particular class method, what exactly is `self` doing? I know what the body of the method is doing i.e. the filtering of the restaurants by city, but how does it run exactly?

Comment: Read this :D https://www.zenspider.com/ruby/quickref.html
also, "def self.my_function" declares a class function whereas "def my_function" declares an instance function. The first one would be called like so: MyClass.my_function. The second one would by called like so: MyClass.new().my_function. One's a static method and ones an instance method.

Comment: also, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429693/singleton-method-vs-class-method

Comment: _kept failing the tests for the #filter_by_city method_ : You don't show us how you actually call `filter_by_city`, so I can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: `self.` is what makes it a _class method_. Without `self.` it would be an _instance method_. So asking what `self` is doing in a class method is somehow like asking what `=` is doing in an assignment :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` is the class `Restaurant`. `def self.method` is how you implement a method on the class itself rather than an instance of the class. `Restaurant.filter_by_city(...)` rather than `Restaurant.new.filter_by_city(...)`.

`self` changes in Ruby depending on context. Within a method, `self` is the object the method was called on.

Within the `class Restaurant` block, and outside of any method, `self` is the `Restaurant` object which is a [Class object](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html). Everything is an object in Ruby. Everything.

You can also do this by declaring a block where the class is the instance.

```
class << self
  def filter_by_city(restaurants, city)
    restaurants.select { |restaurant| restaurant.city == city }
  end
end
```

Normally you'd use this syntax if you have a lot of class methods.

See [Self in Ruby: A Comprehensive Overview](https://airbrake.io/blog/ruby/self-ruby-overview) for more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link - very helpful. So, in this instance, unlike the method #rate which I can call as an instance i.e. check = Restaurant.new(..), check.rate, I'm assuming I can't do the same for the #self.filter_by_city method? If that's the case, why make it a self. when I can make it private?

Comment: Instead of `def self.filter_by_city` you could also write (or think of) `def Restaurant.filter_by_city` which closely resembles the way you would call such class method.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, but don't write it that way; it will break if the class name changes or if the [method is extracted](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method) to a different class or module.

Comment: @BuiltByDan Private is a different thing entirely. Private methods can't be called outside the class they're declared in. This method is intended to be called by users of the Restaurant class. They pass in an Array (or any Enumerable) of Restaurants, and a city, and it returns only those Restaurants in that city. This particular method is a bit silly, the code is trivial, but sometimes you'd do this to hide implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a method in ruby you can optionally explicitly define that method's receiver using `def <receiver>.<method>` syntax instead of plain `def <method>`

```
object = Object.new

def object.foo
  :foo
end

object.foo #=> foo
```

The receiver must either be a singular reference OR an expression (but it must be enclosed by brackets):

```
a = [Object.new, Object.new]

def (a.first).foo
  :foo
end

def (a[1]).bar
  :bar
end

a[0].foo #=> :foo
a.last.bar #=> :bar
a.first.bar #=> undefined method
```

When receiver is defined, the method is defined directly on the receiver's singleton class, ignoring the context in which the method is defined:

```
class A
  o = Obejct.new
  
  def o.foo
  end
end

A.new.foo #=> undefined method
```

Even though method foo was defined in class A body, it is not available to its instances because of the explicit receiver

`self` is a ruby keyword returning the current "context". Inside the methods, `self` is (usually) a receiver of the call, and inside the module `self` returns that module. So:

```
module Wrapper
  module SomeModule
    puts self.name
  end
end
```

will print `Wrapper::SomeModule`.

This means that:

```
class A
  def self.foo
  end
end
```

Is exactly the same as:

```
class A
  def A.foo
  end
end
```

So, the method is defined directly on `A` and can only be called directly on the class as `A.foo`, rather than on its instances.

Comment: In the latter example, you could even move `def A.foo` outside the class body. BTW, what do you mean by "singular reference"?

Comment: That's wild, I didn't know the receiver could an expression! Also: don't do that in real code.